# Change the scroll of an hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, hidden

I have an hidden div with a fixed height and a scrollbar. I would like to change the scroll position, but the browser won't le me do it, as the div is hidden.
The scrollTop property will stick to 0.

Also, I don't want to show and hide the div back, which causes flickering.

If anyone knows how to do it, it'll be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you change the scroll position when you unhide it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question was not complete. The div is not hidden on his own. It's part of a container div, which is hidden. The inner div displays with his parent.

```
<div class="container hidden">
    <div id="some_div">Content</div>
    <div id="my_div">I wanted to scroll this one</div>
    <div id="other_div">Content</div>
</div>
```

We use jQuery came up with a custom "onShow" event.

So now we can do this:

```
$('#my_div').bind('show', function() {
    handle_scrollTopOffset();
});
```

When the show event is bound, it adds the class `.onShow` to the div. And the `jQuery.fn.show()` function has been overridden to trigger the 'show' event on the childs which have the `.onShow` class.

Thanks everyone for their suggestions. I'm sorry I provided a uncomplete question. I'll give all the details next time.

Comment: This was the best solution I found. Instead of an event I just moved the scrollTop() function from my closing function to my opening one.

Answer (score 3):

You can save the scroll using jQuery's data function.

```
function SaveScroll(val)
{
    $(the_element).data("Scroll", val);
}

function Show()
{
    var element = $(the_element);

    // prevent from showing while scrolling
    element.css
    ({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "-50000px",
        left: "-50000px",
        display: ""
    });

    // Scroll to the position set when it was hidden
    element.scrollTop(element.data("Scroll"));

    // show the element
    element.css
    ({
        position: "",
        top: "",
        left: ""
    });
}
```

This might do the trick

---

You maybe can just use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`. The visibility keeps the element where it is. I believe it is the exact same thing as `opacity: 0`, but it is a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent div flickering and fix `<div>` unavailability for scripts you can use position hiding instead of `"display: none;"`:

```
.hidden {
  position: absolute !important;
  left: -9999px !important;
  top: -9999px !important;
}
```